# How to solve the multiple definition in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, include

I don´t know why I got this problem, the header files are just included once but it continuous showing the error, I also already check the .pro file and every SOURCE is just included once. How can I solve this? 
I will attach the files I'm using and their include and the code of the little ones

globals.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include <QtGlobal>
#include "structs.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

struct ListaPaquetes;

QT_END_NAMESPACE

extern ListaPaquetes *nuevoPaquete;

#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_startButton_clicked();

    void on_planificarProduButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

produccion.h (only the first lines)

```
#ifndef PRODUCCION_H
#define PRODUCCION_H

#include <QDialog>
```

structs.h (onyl first lines)
Here is the struct ListaPaquetes, which is the responsible of the error, so the problem I guess is with this file but I don't know why

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H
#define STRUCT_H

#include <QString>
#include <QList>

struct Nodo
{
    int cantidad;
    QString tipoPaquete;
    Nodo *siguiente;
    Nodo *anterior;

    Nodo(){}

    Nodo (int cant, QString paquete)
    {
        cantidad = cant;
        tipoPaquete = paquete;
        siguiente = nullptr;
        anterior = nullptr;
    }
};

struct ListaPaquetes
{
    Nodo *pn;

    ListaPaquetes()
    {
        pn = nullptr;
    }

    void crearPaquete(int,QString);
    QList<QString> paquetesAgregados();

};

void ListaPaquetes::crearPaquete(int cant, QString paquete)
{
    if (pn==nullptr)
    {
        pn = new Nodo(cant, paquete);
        pn->siguiente = pn;
        pn->anterior = pn;
    }
    else
    {
        Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo(cant, paquete);
        pn->anterior->siguiente=nuevo;
        nuevo->anterior = pn->anterior;
        nuevo->siguiente=pn;
        pn->anterior = nuevo;
    }
}

QList<QString> ListaPaquetes::paquetesAgregados()
{
    QList <QString> paquetes;
    if (pn!=nullptr)
    {
        Nodo *tmp = pn;
        do
        {
            paquetes.append(tmp->tipoPaquete);
            tmp = tmp->siguiente;
        }while(tmp!=pn);
    }
    return paquetes;
}

#endif // STRUCT_H
```

globals.cpp

```
#include "globals.h"

ListaPaquetes *nuevoPaquete = new ListaPaquetes();
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QColor>
#include <QColormap>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "produccion.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    if(ui->cantGalletas->text() == "")
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Debe introducir una cantidad de 
        galletas");
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_planificarProduButton_clicked()
{
    Produccion *ventanaPaquetes = new Produccion();
    ventanaPaquetes->show();
}
```

produccion.cpp (When I run something from here, it shows the error)

```
#include "produccion.h"
#include "ui_produccion.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "globals.h"
```

Here are the errors:

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `#include <QString>` and `#include <qstring.h>`? Not that it makes a difference, but those are the same thing. You don't show the error in the question. Which symbol is defined twice?

Comment: I agree with @nwp also why you have two include of : `#include <qdialog.h>` & `#include <QDialog>`

Comment: @nwp I already add some code and the errors, hope you can help me. Also I eliminate the `<qstring.h>` and the `<qdialog.h>` and nothing changes.

Comment: Show also the compilation commands. The error messages should be shown as code text (four spaces at start of each line), not as an image.

Comment: In QtCreator you can switch to the "Compile output" tab to see the actual commands and errors and you can easily copy paste them in your question.

Comment: @FabricioCeciliano - include library headers **first**, and then include your headers **afterwards**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the problem because you are putting the implementation of member functions in header files (here *structs.h*). Every source file that includes *globals.h* will include *structs.h* and compile the functions implemented there. When you link your program these functions are multiply defined

You need to move `ListaPaquetes::crearPaquete(int cant, QString paquete)` and
`ListaPaquetes::crearPaquete(int cant, QString paquete)` into *structs.cpp*

Comment: Any solution? Because still I can't solve the problem

Comment: I edited the answer: move the member function implementations into *structs.cpp*